# PlayGamesPlatform could not be found in IOS platform

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I currently have a working android game publish in google play store with inapp purchase and achievements. I would like to make a new version for IOS. But when a change platform to IOS, `PlayGamesPlatform could not be found` error shows. Do I have to delete all scripts related to google play or is there a way to have them both for android and IOS using a condtion? I also tried adding `NO_GPGS` in Scripting Define Symbols but error still shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Unity Platform Dependent Compilers [Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)
. When using Google Play Store IAP, use if UNITY_ANDROID then add play store code inside. For IOS use UNITY_IOS.

Comment: [Google Play Game Services Plugin For UNITY](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) "[NOTICE: This version of the plugin no longer supports iOS. Google Play games services for iOS is deprecated, and is not likely to function as expected. Do not use Google Play games services for iOS in new apps. See the deprecation announcement blog post for more details.]"